# Facebook php sdk configuration with localhost wamp and eclipse pdt

Tags: php, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook development. I have downloaded facebook php-sdk and copied it into www folder of wamp server. I have downloaded eclipse pdt too. But I am blank now on that what else is needed to develop facebook app. When I try to run sample examples of facebook php-sdk's php file then it throws exception:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.' in C:\wamp\www\mysampletest\facebook-php-sdk-master\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 19
Please tell me what configuration needs to be done to run examples of facebook php sdk. If I am unaware of any pre-requisites needed to develop facebook app and hence the issue is occurring then please kindly tell the pre-requisites needed to develop facebook app.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Facebook PHP requires following things to work proper:

1) PHP's [CURL extension](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/) must be installed and enabled.

2) Your Facebook App ID and App Secret for the respective App.

3) Your App should allow the URLs where you are running the application (canvas url).

If these requirements are met, Facebook API works fine.